# MIPS Assembly Program to access elements in the 4x4 matrix, row or column-major oder

Tags: matrix, assembly

This MIPS Assembly program will make you access the elements in the 4x4 matrix in either row or column-major order i.e. accessing all elements row by row or column by column.

Output is posted below as well.

Data section has variables declared, Text section has the main function.

This took me several days to put together since I just started this from scratch. 
I'll appreciate any feedback.
I also hope this helps out those who are looking to to some matrix calculations and such.

```
# Data Section
.data
    .globl array

    .align 4
    array: .float 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 10.00, 11.00, 12.00, 13.00, 14.00, 15.00, 16.00

    matrix_size: .word 4 
    float_size: .word 4

    lb_:    .asciiz "Print in row or column-major order\n" #uncomment a line in ADDING OFFSET section to change which to print (can't print both at the same time!)

    j_:     .asciiz "j: "
    k_:     .asciiz " k: "
    bar_:   .asciiz " | "
    colon:  .asciiz ": "
    lineBrk: .asciiz "\n"

    # MIPS Printing Syntax
    # li $v0  n     # n = 1:(print_integer), 2:(print_float), 4:(print_str)
    # la $a0 text_  # text_ should be defined in the .data section above beforehand
    # syscall


# Text Section
.text
    .globl main
main:
    #Print title
    li $v0 4    
    la $a0 lb_
    syscall

    la $a1 array 
    move $s7 $a1 # base address of array

    lw $s1 matrix_size # $s1 = matrix_size
    lw $s2 float_size # $s2 = float_size


li $t5 0 # j counter
jloop:
    li $t6 0 # k counter
    # j kloop
        kloop:
            #Print j and k value
            #j: t5 
            #k: t6

            li $v0 4        # "j"
            la $a0 j_
            syscall

            li $v0 1 
            move $a0 $t5
            syscall         # value_j


            li $v0 4        # "k"
            la $a0 k_
            syscall

            li $v0 1 
            move $a0 $t6
            syscall         # value_k

            li $v0 4        # " | "
            la $a0 bar_
            syscall 

        ## Caculate column major offset
                # $s0 = offset result
                # $s1 = matrix_size: 4
                # $s2 = float_size: 4
                # $s7 = base address stored
                # $t5 = j
                # $t6 = k

                # offset = 4*(4*k + j) = float_size * (matrix_size*k + j)

            mul $s0 $s1 $t6 # s0 = 4*k
            add $s0 $s0 $t5 # s0 = s0 + j
            mul $s0 $s0 $s2 # s0 = 4*s0, offset stored in s0


            # print( offset: )
            li $v0 1
            move $a0 $s0
            syscall

            li $v0 4    
            la $a0 colon
            syscall


        #### ADDING OFFSET ####

            # This will increase the memory address. It's like increasing the index for accessing next element. 
            # addi $a1 $a1 4    #row major    -> new_addr += 4  (cumulatively increase the address to access the array by 4)
            add $a1 $s7 $s0     #column major -> new addr = base_addr + offset

            # print( element\n )
            lwc1 $f12 0($a1)
            li $v0 2    
            syscall 

            li $v0 4    
            la $a0 lineBrk
            syscall 

            # k_counter++
            addi $t6 $t6 1 
            bne $t6 $s1 kloop

    # j_counter++
    addi $t5 $t5 1 
    bne $t5 $s1 jloop


#Done, terminate program
    li $v0, 10
        syscall

.end main
```

Output: #0,16,32.. etc. are the offset added to the base address

## it is in multiple of 4 since floats are 4 bytes

[image]

Comment: I know the mods are going to yell at me again, but since I (still) don't speak MIPS, I can only ask questions, not make recommendations. So: Why does it look like you are declaring `array` 3 times?  If those other 2 are commented out (as they appear), remove them before asking for a CR. It appears that `matrix_size` and `float_size` are declared as variables instead of [equ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13677162/2189500)? Does it make sense to do `j kloop` when the next line is kloop? Why does your comment say `"j"` when you are printing k? Add " " to k_ to avoid extra print? Oops I'm out of sp

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thank you very much. 1) For the array, they are comments to just help me understand. I should get rid of them or call the actual array being used differently yes. 2) I did not know about .equ at all. I've only did this for 5 days now. 3) Somehow I thought I had to specify in Assembly to enter a loop but i guess you don't have to! It still runs fine 4) fixed the typo in the comment, and yes I can just simply add space " " instead of making a character... thank you

Comment: MARS/SPIM has `.eqv` I believe, `.equ` is ignored (and overall the MARS/SPIM assembler parser is quite crude, I think it can't evaluate any expression (like `.eqv zzz 5*30` ... or if it works in eqv, then surely it does not in `lw` argument), etc.. which makes some things a bit painful, when one is used to modern powerful assembler from other platforms.

Comment: I see. Well I'll stick to lw for now. I almost got the multiplication working except it doesn't update the index of array2 properly. I'm almost there... https://codeshare.io/5e3AQK

Comment: This is really stressing me out :( I don’t know why it is printing out wrong things... Could you please take a look? @Ped7g. I updated the above link in the comment

Comment: @Leonard is it supposed to multiply two matrices? Because at this moment that code from link does only Cij = Aij * Bji, C is not matrix of products of the row x columns vectors multiplication. But everything else seems reasonable solid about that code, indices, offsets, registers usage, no redundant/random code, etc... I just dislike the interleaved `.data/.text` segments, because I still think in terms of old 8 bit machines assemblers, where was no segment, so defining data inside code would break everything, but MARS/SPIM will correctly put that into different memory areas.

Comment: @Ped7g Yes! It's supposed to do the matrix vector multiplication... I got it working in Python and C but just failing really hard here. Did I mess up my indexing? Sorry I worked with j,k instead of i,j

Comment: Oh now that you mention it, I guess I'm not properly doing the addition part.. I think I see it now? in python syntax, in R[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j], this += part is where I'm messing up i guess

Comment: also need to put back i i loop perhaps. ill come back

Comment: @Leonard yup, you have like only 2 nested loops where you need 3 of them, I didn't bother to follow your i/j/k when I was describing what your code does, so I just used "i, j". Arrays in python and C are doing lot of the stuff behind the curtain, like the pointer-math adjusted by element type, etc. If you are new to assembly, you are doing so far very good, and this matrix multiplication is not that simple as first task, so that thing you did with this piece of code in code review was IMO right thing, giving you some basic experience and some skill with the tools. Baby steps... ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79803/discussion-between-leonard-and-ped7g).